# Unable to stop a while loop in a Thread by changing it's boolean condition

Tags: java

I decided to build a application framework for my next semester to save time on making projects and also learn more about java, I would just have to create a new Application(), send it a window and other requirements and then call application.start

Application extends Thread, the run() opens up a jframe which is a home made console that allow me to interact with the code and then goes into a while loop where i will insert code for a clock just like a video game.

when i type /exit in the console, it calls the terminate() function in Application which does send the console a closing message and does change the Boolean running to false, finishing the loop, disposing of the windows and then closing the thread and thus closing the program.

For some reason that my apprentice level of knowledge does not know, the loop seems keep running.

By calling a command I made in the console that sends back the value of the Boolean running, I have determined that the console command exit does indeed work and changed the Boolean value to false, but the loop keeps going. I tried inserting the minecraft loop in but it also does not stop, putting the thread to sleep even of 1 millisecond does work and the program closes like intended.

```
//where the application is started from

public static void main( String[] args ) {

        Application app = new Application("Test");

        app.start();
    }
//Application Class
public class Application extends Thread {

    static boolean running;
@Override
    public void run() {
        if ( true ) {
            console.open();
        }

        while ( running ) {

        }

        if ( window != null ) {
            window.dispose();
        }

        Console.dispose();

    }

    public static  void terminate() {
        Console.input( "Closing ..." );
        running = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: You need condition variables or atomic boolean or volatile boolean.

Comment: Are you sure that `Console.input( "Closing ..." );` returns ? add a print after it to verify.

Comment: making it volatile worked, i'm in college still and we have barely touched Thread so I was not aware of visibility problems between 2 threads, I knew that the jframe was running it's own thread but I was not aware that there could be problems with interacting with an other thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use volatile variable

```
    //Application Class
public class Application extends Thread {
 private volatile boolean run_T = true;
    static boolean running;
@Override
    public void run() {
        if ( run_T ) {
            console.open();
        }

        while ( run_T ) {

        }

        if ( window != null ) {
            run_T=true;
            window.dispose();
        }

        Console.dispose();

    }

    public static  void terminate() {
        Console.input( "Closing ..." );
        running = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I barely touched threads at school so I was not aware of volatiles and how thread works